# Understanding Windows Server container and Hyper-V container

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to understand Windows Docker container. I have searched the web for Docker and as per my understanding, Windows Server container runs on top of host OS kernel mode. Host OS kernel share the kernel to container for getting any machine related activities. But Hyper-V containers have their own kernel. That means:

1. For Hyper-V containers, each container has its own kernel and that kernel will get all machine related activities so there is no need of host OS kernel. Is this correct?
2. If above question is correct, why there is a dependency between version of container OS and host OS. As the Hyper-V container contains its own kernel. There should be no version or OS dependency between container and host OS. Both should run independently.
3. for Windows Server container, as per my understanding, layers between images are shared. Eg. If I pull a image IMG1 which has base layer as Windows Server core, and if I pull another image IMG2 which also contains base layer as Windows Server core, Docker will not pull Windows Server core for IMG2 instead it shares the base layer of IMG1 to IMG2. Does the same applies to Hyper-V container, in other words do two Hyper-V container shares the base layer as there are like VMs?

Comment: This is rather broad for Stack Overflow. I am minded to ask that it is narrowed down to one question, but I wonder also whether it might be recommended as a better fit on _Server Fault_.